# Adding content to custom taxonomy category pages

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I can't figure out or find an answer on how to enable the description in the custom taxonomy category pages. Under description field it says: "The description is not prominent by default; however, some themes may show it.".

I've managed to enable it to normal category pages by adding this code to archive.php

```
<?php echo category_description(); ?>
```

But it's still disabled on taxonomy pages.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Problem solved**

I find out that my theme has taxonomy.php where this code

```
<?php echo term_description(); ?>
```

needs to be added to make the description visible on custom taxonomy page.

Thanks to @PieterGoosen for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the description from a taxonomy term, you can use `echo term_description( $term_id, $taxonomy );` where `$term_id` is the term ID of the current term and `$taxonomy` is the taxonomy the term belongs to.

For general use on your taxonomy page, you can just use `echo term_description();`

Comment: Thanks. Now I have these two lines added to my theme archive.php 
<?php echo term_description(); ?>

<?php echo category_description(); ?> but it still only works on regular category pages, but not on custom taxonomy page...

Comment: Works for me, are you sure your term has a description, are you sure your custom taxonomy uses archive.php. Are you even talking about terms here?

Comment: you are right, my taxonomy isn't using archive.php. It uses taxonomy.php. Thanks!